# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to List

Tags: java

I got this error: "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to List" in "subLists"` "and `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String"` in `"accList"`

Code:

```
ArrayList subLists = new ArrayList();

for (List accList : subLists) {
        service.submit(() -> {
            for (String account : accList) {
                accounts.remove(account);
                String[] split = account.split(":");
                String email = split[0];
                String password = split[1];
                AuthResult result = null;
```

Comment: don't use raw types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify what type of object was in the different `lists`, you need to, the programm won't guess :

```
List<List<String>> subLists = new ArrayList<>();  

for (List<String> accList : subLists) {
    service.submit(() -> {
        for (String account : accList) {
// ...
```

*Also, better use `Interfaces` than `Implementations` to store the variable, easier to update (`List<List<String>> rather than ArrayList<List<String>>`*

Comment: I'd use `List<List<String>> subLists` instead of `ArrayList<List<String>> subLists` :)

Comment: @Aominè me tooo, but I'd just correct the problem, the limit is hard to find between answering(correcting) and improving